# Add Woocommerce booking product to cart programmatically

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am trying to programmatically add a booking to the shopping cart.  I have been looking into the code for this and have found and tried the following:

Method 1:  `$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id);`

Method 2:  `WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );`

Neither of which are working for me with the latest release of woocommerce bookings.

The code works for simple products in woocommerce without issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated